# MS Access SQL query refreshes and loses values. if saved as query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to use MS Access and got a running query, see end of question.

My problem is as soon as I save my query in MS Access and open it again, one column only shows its values for a few seconds and then gets refreshed to empty cells.

Is there any configuration or change on my query I can do, so it simply just shows the values without any strange/breaking refreshes?

```
SELECT  [Time Stamp]
        ,[Assay]
        ,[Project]
        ,[Direction]
        ,[Email]
        ,[Messung]
        ,[NextDirection]
        ,[Duration_ss]
FROM (
    SELECT OT.[ID]
           ,OT.[Time Stamp]
           ,OT.[Assay]
           ,OT.[Project]
           ,OT.[Direction]
           ,OT.[Email]
           ,OT.[Messung]
           ,(
                Select Top 1 Direction
                FROM [tbl_HistoryLog] IT 
                WHERE IT.Assay = OT.Assay and IT.Project = OT.Project 
                ORDER BY IT.[Time Stamp] DESC
            ) AS NextDirection
            ,DATEDIFF("s",[Time Stamp],(
                        Select Top 1 [Time Stamp] 
                        FROM [tbl_HistoryLog] IT 
                        WHERE IT.Assay = OT.Assay 
                        and IT.Project = OT.Project 
                        and IT.ID <> OT.ID
                        ORDER BY IT.[Time Stamp] DESC)
            ) AS Duration_ss 

           FROM tbl_HistoryLog AS OT 
       )  AS RT
WHERE ( [Direction] NOT LIKE 'CheckOut' and [Direction] <>[NextDirection]);
```

[image]

5 sec later ...

[image]

**Edit**

Raw Data:

```
ID  |Time Stamp             |Assay      |Project    |Direction  |Email  |Messung
1   |11.01.2021 12:15:11    |text123    |project1   |CheckIn    |##     |#####
2   |11.01.2021 12:16:12    |text123    |project2   |CheckIn    |##     |#####
3   |11.01.2021 12:14:13    |text456    |project3   |CheckIn    |##     |#####
4   |11.01.2021 12:56:47    |text456    |project3   |Checkout   |##     |#####
```

Result data:

```
ID  |Time Stamp             |Assay      |Project    |Direction  |Email  |Messung    |NextDirection  |Duration_ss
3   |11.01.2021 12:14:13    |text456    |project3   |CheckIn    |##     |#####      |Checkout       |2554
```

`NextDirection` loses values after few seconds. I guess the query tries to update, but does not fully run somehow...

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data as text table, not image.

Comment: You could try changing the **Recordset type** of the query from Dynaset to Snapshot.

Comment: @Andre  That sounds promising, but it seems like this is only a Thing in VB. My Application written in another language runs fine with this. I would like to set this behavior in access

Comment: You can. It's a property of the query in design view.